# Problem rendering items in select (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am trying to load the options of a select depending on another select. I extract the data from an array (which will later have much more data).

My problem is that the second select loads the correct items BUT in a single options and not separately.
[image: screenshot error]

Any idea what I'm failing? I am a newbie in react. I apologize if the code is very horrible! Any help will be welcome.

P.S. I don't know if it makes any difference in this case, but I'm using "Ant Design".

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Form, Select, Input } from 'antd';


export default function SelectPetZone(props) {
    const { publicationData, setPublicationData } = props;
    const { Option } = Select;

    const arrayZones = [
      {
        departmentName: "Montevideo",
        neighborhood: ['Centro', 'Cordón', 'Flor de Maroñas', 'Manga']
      },
      {
        departmentName: "Canelones",
        neighborhood: ['Las Piedras', 'El Dorado', 'Progreso', 'La Paz']
      }
    ];

    const optionsDepartments = [];
    const [optionsNeighborhood, setoptionsNeighborhood] = useState([]);


    for(const item of arrayZones) {
        optionsDepartments.push(<Option key={item.departmentName} value={item.departmentName}> { item.departmentName } </Option>);
    }


    const chargeNeighborhood = e => {
        // Set department
        setPublicationData({ ...publicationData, department: e });
        
        let arrayDepartment = arrayZones.filter(function(i) {                
            return i.departmentName === e;
        });

        let arrayNeighborhood = arrayDepartment.map(function(i) {
            console.log(i.neighborhood); // => Print array with correct values
            return <Option key={i.neighborhood} value={i.neighborhood}>{i.neighborhood}</Option>;
        })

        setoptionsNeighborhood(arrayNeighborhood);
    }



    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col lg={6}>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Select placeholder='Departamento' onChange={chargeNeighborhood} value={publicationData.department} >
                            {optionsDepartments}
                        </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Col>
                <Col lg={6} offset={3}>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Select placeholder='Barrio' onChange={e => setPublicationData({ ...publicationData, neighborhood: e })} value={publicationData.neighborhood} >                            
                            {optionsNeighborhood}
                        </Select>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}
```

In chargeNeighbourhood function I also tried to do this but did not get a good result:

```
const chargeNeighborhood = e => {
        // Set department
        setPublicationData({ ...publicationData, department: e });
        
       
        // Load neighborhood      
        for(const i of arrayZones) { 
            if(e === i.departmentName) {
                for(const j of i.neighborhood) {  
                    // console.log(j); 
                    setoptionsNeighborhood([...optionsNeighborhood, <Option value={j} key={j}>{j}</Option>]);                   
                }            
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mapping `arrayDepartment` inside `changeNeighborhood` and, if I understand your problem correctly, after you get the right department, you should be mapping `arrayDepartment.neighborhood` to map every neighborhood string into an `Option`.

For clarity, it would be a good idea to change that property name from `neighborhood` to `neighborhoods` since it's a list of neighborhoods.

In your comment, it seems like you already concluded that `neighborhood` is an array when you have this line:

`console.log(i.neighborhood); // => Print array with correct values`

So when you set your `value` for the `Option` component, you're actually passing an entire array:

`<Option key={i.neighborhood} value={i.neighborhood}>{i.neighborhood}</Option>`

That's why you're seeing all options as an array. `Option` is just converting that list into a string by concatenating every element of the array.

Comment: Thanks! I took your advice and managed to fix it. I mark your answer as a solution to my problem.